# Qt Designer - Why does number get pushed to the left when LCD Number is resized?

Tags: qt

I am building a very basic calculator demo application in Qt Designer (Qt Version: 5.15.2). I notice that when I resize the window, the digits in the LCD Number display get pushed to the left. Why does this occur?

Before resize:

[image: Before resize]

After resize:

[image: After resize]

Comment: Here is the contents of the .ui file: https://pastebin.com/B8eqUArA

Comment: Are you seeing any warnings or errors in the console about binding loops or transitions or anything?  If so, Qt will some times give up fully fleshing out the layout, because it doesn't quite know what to do.

Comment: There are no warnings or errors in the console when I convert the .ui to .py and use the layout in a basic PyQt5 program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put one `horizontalSpacer` The out put is like this , Try this :

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>473</width>
    <height>274</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="3" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="radicalButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>√</string>
        </property>
        <property name="flat">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="mMinusButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>M-</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="3">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="equalsButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>=</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="offButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>OFF</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="4">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="timesButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>×</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="3">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button9">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>9</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="acButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>AC</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="percentButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>%</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button2">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>2</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="cButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>C</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="3">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button3">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>3</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="4">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="divideButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>÷</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="dotButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>.</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button4">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>4</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="5" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button0">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>0</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button1">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>1</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="mrcButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>MRC</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button5">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>5</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="3">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="mPlusButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>M+</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="1">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button7">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>7</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button8">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>8</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="3">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="button6">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>6</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="3" column="4">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="minusButton">
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>-</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="4" column="4" rowspan="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="plusButton">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>+</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="4">
       <widget class="QLCDNumber" name="lcdNumber">
        <property name="enabled">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="cursor">
         <cursorShape>ForbiddenCursor</cursorShape>
        </property>
        <property name="autoFillBackground">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShape">
         <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="frameShadow">
         <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="smallDecimalPoint">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="digitCount">
         <number>1</number>
        </property>
        <property name="segmentStyle">
         <enum>QLCDNumber::Flat</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="value" stdset="0">
         <double>0.000000000000000</double>
        </property>
        <property name="intValue" stdset="0">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="0" colspan="4">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: This does solve the problem of the digits moving to the left, so I will mark it as accepted. However, this does make the display much smaller than I would like.

Comment: set digital count 1 instead of 10 .

Comment: if you want to show numbers with 10 digits you need more space and because of that, it shows smaller .